# Custom ListView one item for a specific screen height

Tags: android, listview

I have coded an app to learn about Custom List View. While the app has no errors, I have one issue. I have shown it in the images as follows.
[IMAGE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsemK.jpg)
[IMAGE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FFXJ.jpg)

The problem is I have to scroll a long way before i can find the next list item.The list items do not appear one below the other.How to resolve this issue?
Here is my code:

```
package com.example.hp.customlistview;

import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int IMAGES[]={R.drawable.adsense, R.drawable.allo, R.drawable.chrome, R.drawable.firebase, R.drawable.youtube};
    String[] NAMES={"AdSense","Allo","Chrome","Firebase","YouTube"};
    String [] DESCRIPTIONS={"Money through ads","Video calling","Web Browser","Cloud Database","Video Streaming"};
    private ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }

    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            Log.d("Length of Array ","The length is "+IMAGES.length);
            return IMAGES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);
            Log.d("Image ID","The id is "+R.id.imageView);
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView textView_name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            TextView textView_desc=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            if(imageView==null)
                Log.d("NULL?","YES IT IS NULL");
            else
                Log.d("NULL?","NO IT IS NOT NULL");
            imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES[i]);
            textView_name.setText(NAMES[i]);
            textView_desc.setText(DESCRIPTIONS[i]);
            Log.d("Hello","Hello there "+textView_name.getText().toString());
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

customlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="161dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="237dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="380dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hp.customlistview.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="386dp"
        android:layout_height="409dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Ok"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/listView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

To resolve this, i tried the following

1)android:layout_height="match_parent" to a specific height of 120 dp.
(It is in customlayout.xml)
But it did not work

2)Used some other layout, such as Absolute and Relative Layout, but image fills up the list content much beyond expected size

EDIT:
I have the list items displayed in a compact manner, as follows,
after suggestions by Ben P. in the comments below.
[IMAGE 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDdyC.jpg)
But the description is not appearing,although clearly i have set it programatically in MainActivity.java
I observed that setting android:layout_height to some custom value makes the description text view disappear in the preview.

If someone is downvoting,please give the reason for doing so. This will help me improve the quality of my questions.

Comment: You definitely don't want to use `match_parent` for the customlayout height; that will make each item the same height as the listview itself. You should use a fixed height or `wrap_content`

Comment: I don't really expect this to fix the problem, but when you inflate the customlayout you should use the call that takes in a parent. That is, you should write this instead of what you have: `view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout, viewGroup, false);`

Comment: Use `wrap_content` for the listview and for the views in custom layout. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Ben P. Thank you,It quite helped, but it doesnt display the description of the items. The list items are stacked without gap between each other. But what is the difference between what you suggested and what i had earlier?

Comment: @Chithra sorry, i tried but the issue persists

Comment: @RahulSeetharaman that's a very complicated question. The answer depends on knowledge of ViewGroups, LayoutParams, and ListView. The short version is that the `viewGroup` param of the `getView()` method is the view that will be the parent of the view you return, and passing it to the `inflate()` call will make your view's `android:layout_xxx` attributes work correctly for that parent.

Comment: Ok, I guess i have a lot to learn:) But thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. Posting it for anyone who may have similar doubts in future.
Set layout height as 120dp or some finite value even before dragging and dropping items.
Now start drag and drop operation on this reduced layout.
Pretty simple i guess. This helped me resolve it.
Here it is:)

[Image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63ko3.jpg)